# Hibernate creates N+1 selects for "diamond shaped" OneToMany relations even though FetchType.EAGER + FetchMode.JOIN are set

Tags: hibernate

I need to fetch a complex object with multiple layers of sub-nodes to the very last leaf (preferrably) in a single query. Each parent has a `@OneToMany` relation to their respective children.

In order to achieve that, I was trying to use `FetchType.EAGER` and `FetchMode.JOIN` on all the `@OneToMany` relations, so when I fetch the topmost object, Hibernate would generate a single query containing all children. However, unfortunately I am running into the N+1 problem. I believe that this is happening because the relationships between my entities form a "diamond shape", like this:

[image: diamond structure diagram]

When I map the relationships as shown in the picture, Hibernate generates N+1 queries. However, if I remove one of the two relations towards `BOTTOM`, then everything works fine and Hibernate does the job in a single query (as expected).

Here is some minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Top")
public class Top {
    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    Set<Left> left;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    Set<Right> right;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Left")
public class Left {
    @Id
    String id;
    String parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    Set<Bottom> bottom;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Right")
public class Right {
    @Id
    String id;
    String parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    Set<Bottom> bottom;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Bottom")
public class Bottom{
    @Id
    String id;
    String parent;
}
```

And the code I use to fetch the `TOP` object:

```java
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

//Some arbitrary known "Top" object
session.get(Top.class, "1");

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

The SQL being generated looks as follows:

```sql
SELECT top0_.id        AS id1_3_0_, 
       left1_.parent   AS parent2_1_1_, 
       left1_.id       AS id1_1_1_, 
       left1_.id       AS id1_1_2_, 
       left1_.parent   AS parent2_1_2_, 
       bottom2_.parent AS parent2_0_3_, 
       bottom2_.id     AS id1_0_3_, 
       bottom2_.id     AS id1_0_4_, 
       bottom2_.parent AS parent2_0_4_, 
       right3_.parent  AS parent2_2_5_, 
       right3_.id      AS id1_2_5_, 
       right3_.id      AS id1_2_6_, 
       right3_.parent  AS parent2_2_6_ 
FROM   Top top0_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Left left1_ 
                    ON top0_.id = left1_.parent 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Bottom bottom2_ 
                    ON left1_.id = bottom2_.parent 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Right right3_ 
                    ON top0_.id = right3_.parent 
WHERE  top0_.id = ? 

SELECT bottom0_.parent AS parent2_0_0_, 
       bottom0_.id     AS id1_0_0_, 
       bottom0_.id     AS id1_0_1_, 
       bottom0_.parent AS parent2_0_1_ 
FROM   Bottom bottom0_ 
WHERE  bottom0_.parent = ?
```

Does anybody know what needs to be changed so that Hibernate generates a single query instead of the N+1? Is this double-selection of the `id` and `parent` columns possibly already a symptom for some underlying problem with the mapping?

By the way, I am using Hibernate 5.3.2.Final.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also opened up this topic as a bug in the Hibernate JIRA. See here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12782

Answer (score 0):

When you are using @OneToMany in parent class (@ManyToOne much better option btw)
you need to use bidirectional relation. Otherwise you will have multiples queries like you have. 
So add in each of your children class @ManyToOne and let them do the mapping.

for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Top")
public class Top {
    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "top", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Left> left = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "top", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Right> right = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Left")
public class Left {
    @Id
    String id;
    String parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "top_id")
    Top top;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Bottom> bottom;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Right")
public class Right {
    @Id
    String id;
    String parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "top_id")
    Top top;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Bottom> bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense to me. However, after modeling it the way you proposed, I still get the N+1 queries. I believe this is because now the `BOTTOM` entity is not mapped bidirectionally to its parents (`LEFT` and `RIGHT`). Is there a way to model the upwards relation in `BOTTOM` without knowing the concrete parent types?

Comment: You can't. 
But you can make @ManyToOne relationship in parent class@ManyToMany
    List<Bottom> bottom=new ArrayList<>();
 So you don't need bidirectional that way.

Comment: Do not use EAGER, set Lazy and create a query with JOIN FETCH or LEFT JOIN FETCH no mitigate the n+1 problem.

Comment: @Moler: I was able to model the upwards relationship in `BOTTOM` using an abstract class and `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, making the relationship bidirectional, but that didn't solve the problem either. `ManyToMany` is also not an option, because my schema is fixed (hope that I understood you correctly here).

Comment: @WilderValera: Setting the FetchType to LAZY would not fit my use case, as I need to serialize the whole structure in one go. With regards to creating the query manually: my motivation to use hibernate was to have it generate the queries automatically as much as possible.

Comment: Eager fetching generally isn't recommended, because that way, Hibernate will always have to fetch the assocations, regardless of the use case, which is almost never what you want. For what do you want to serialize it for? JSON/XML response from a webservice?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: Exactly, we need to serialize the whole object for a webservice response. Unfortunately, the standard we are implementing requires us to resolve the full object, so lazy loading is not an option. Neither is a document store, we need to use a fully normalized relational schema.

Comment: In that case I can only recommend you to implement a DTO approach since you also rarely want to serialize the whole entity state. Instead of using DTOs you could also use JPAs entity graph feature to specify the fetch graph along with a few @JsonIgnores, but IMO the best solution is to use DTOs. Maybe take a look at https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage to reduce boilerplate.